# Capture pattern group in case statements in bash scripts

Tags: regex, bash, switch-statement, regex-group

A typical `case` statement in `bash` could be:

```
k=abcdef
case $k in
    "abc"* )
        echo "pattern found"
        ;;
esac
```

One of my variables have the pattern `key=value`, and I wish to extract the value from it.

```
k="abc=value1"
case $k in
    "abc="* )
        echo "key abc found";
        # extract "value1"
        ;;
esac
```

How do I extract the value from the key? Like `key1=(.*)` and get the captured group by saying `$1` or `\1`.

Comment: just `echo ${k#*=}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match the substring with a regex you have and access Group 1 using `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`:

```
k="abc=value1"
rx='abc=(.*)'
if [[ $k =~ $rx ]]; then
    echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]};
fi
# => value1
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/OXGZOZ19445)

Note that it is the most straight-forward way to use a regex by declaring it in a separate variable, so that the code works as expected in all Bash versions supporting the `=~` match operator. Beginning with [Bash 3.2](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS), `[[ $k =~ "abc=(.*)" ]]` like code will trigger literal string comparison rather than a regex comparison:

> f.  Quoting the string argument to the `[[` command's  `=~` operator now forces
>       string matching, as with the other pattern-matching operators.

A regex makes sense if you have a complex scenario. In your case, [*string manipulations*](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) like [the one pynexj suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51155258/capture-pattern-group-in-case-statements-in-bash-scripts/51155366#comment89293767_51155258) will also work:

```
k="abc=value1"
echo ${k#*=}
# => value1
```

See [another demo online](https://ideone.com/Ny9O7o). Here, `#` triggers substring removal of the shortest substring between the start of string and the first `=` char (including it). See documentation:

> **Substring Removal**
>
> `${string#substring}`
>           Deletes shortest match of $substring from front of $string.

Comment: i bet the inexperienced bash users will be surprised that `[[ $k =~ "$rx" ]]` (or `[[ $k =~ "abc=(.*)" ]]`) would not work. u better explain a bit more on this. :)

Comment: @pynexj Yeah, that won't work since that would trigger literal string check.

Comment: Woah! I've barely done bash scripting. This is amazing! You can do anything using a bash script. :D

Comment: @JohnStrood What can't be done in Bash, can be nailed with awk, sed, grep and surely Perl.

Comment: Also, while accepting this answer, I'd like to add that although the power of regex is unparalleled, in this particular use case that I'm parsing parameters to the script, I'd go with `echo ${k#*=}` inside switch `case`. However, I could've gone with `if-elif` too.